# How to do such substitutions with AWK or sed or Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, sed, awk

Want to substitute multiplication symbol "*" with "tensor", and the power symbol "^" with "p_tensor" using following substitution rules:

```
    a(k)^n --> p_tensor(n,a(k))
    a(i)*a(j) --> tensor(a(i),a(j)), when i=/=j
```

But when the symbol "*" is between a number and a(i), such as 3*a(i), we should keep the  symbol "*" as what it is.

so for example,

```
    5*a(i)*a(j)*(a(k1)+3*a(k2)) --> 5*tensor(tensor(a(i),a(j)),a(k1)+3*a(k2))
    a(i)^2*a(j)^2  --> tensor(p_tensor(2,a(i)),p_tensor(2,a(j)))
    ...
```

Now I want to reformat the following expression using AWK or sed or Perl:

```
    3*a(3)^2+6*a(1)^2*(5*a(2)^2-2*a(4))+6*a(2)*a(4)+6*a(1)*(-4*a(2)*a(3)+a(5))
```

Any ideas how?

The expected result after substitution should be

```
    3*p_tensor(2,a(3))+6*tensor(p_tensor(2,a(1)),(5*p_tensor(2,a(2))-2*a(4))+6*tensor(a(2),a(4))+6*tensor(a(1),(-4*tensor(a(2),a(3))+a(5))
```

Comment: Why do you replace some of the `*` with `tensor`, but not others? Ie, the first `3*a(3)^2` seems like it should be `tensor(3,p_tensor(2,a(3))`.

Comment: Yes, I should mention this, "tensor" is only used to replace symbol "*" which is a binary operator between two a(i).

Comment: I can't think of a simple way to do it, especially with that special case... At least not in any clean way. You might want to look into parsing the original expression into an expression tree, and then converting that to use your operations where necessary.

Comment: Since parentheses are involved, you'll most likely have to set up a parser of some kind to tokenize the input and deal with each token individually.

Comment: @JackManey Any idea how to set up a parser of some kind to tokenize the input and deal with each token individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regular expressions cannot do arbitrary nesting, nor can then do precedence and associativity. Parsers are required for that; however, you can get close enough by starting with this:

Perl:

```
while(<>) {
   s/(a\(\d+\))\^(\d+)/p_tensor($2,$1)/g;
   s/(a\((\d+)\))\*(a\((\d+)\))/tensor($1, $3)/g if $2 != $4;
   print;
}
```

which is close, and gets you a single level. The extra nesting can then be "faked" by adding additional recursively defined patterns that go to whatever max nesting depth you need (often not many...expressions are rarely 3-4 levels deep in practice, which may be fine for you).

Try it with:

```
echo "3*a(3)^2+6*a(1)^2*(5*a(2)^2-2*a(4))+6*a(2)*a(4)+6*a(1)*(-4*a(2)*a(3)+a(5))" | perl t.pl
```

or something similar.

Comment: Could you illustrate the perl substitution rule for a complete translation of "6*a(1)^2*(5*a(2)^2-2*a(4))" to "6*tensor(p_tensor(2,a(1)),(5*p_tensor(2,a(2))-2*a(4))". With current script, it is translated into "6*p_tensor(2,a(1))*(5*p_tensor(2,a(2))-2*a(4))".

Comment: I'm not sure what rule you are following...the rule you gave for products involved things of the form a(i). If you are saying that you need to take arbitrary products of all kinds and turn them into calls of tensor, then you will need a parser, unfortunately. You can write such a thing in perl, but it will be ugly (you'd have to pre-count the parens, and such). There are really nice tools out there for doing this. See GNU bison or ANTLR.